# Getting an error when dispatching in redux, redux-thunk

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-thunk

I randomly started getting this error:

```
Argument of type 'ThunkAction<void, CombinedState<{ tasks: TaskState; }>, ServiceLocator, Action<string>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
  Property 'type' is missing in type 'ThunkAction<void, CombinedState<{ tasks: TaskState; }>, ServiceLocator, Action<string>>' but required in type 'AnyAction'.
```

when I try to do this:

```
store.dispatch(fetchTasks(null));
```

These are the types:

```
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof reducer>;

export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<
  ReturnType,
  RootState,
  ServiceLocator, // Extra argument
  Action<string>
>;
```

Store:

```
export default createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument(serviceLocator))
);
```

Comment: What is the fetchTasks action creator?

Comment: @HMR it is a plain method that uses redux-thunk to make an api call.